# Crossover amp selection question

Tags: chevrolet, car, audio, silverado

I have a 2012 Chevy Silverado C1500 with factory (non-bose) sound.

I have upgraded my speakers using Kicker DSC65/DSC654, and now am looking to add a amp for the speakers.

I am interested in a unit that has four high level inputs which splits the rear input with a crossover for a subwolfer. It should then have five/six pair of high level outputs.

I've done extensive research, but I'm afraid I don't know how to look for this. So far my solution involves combining a crossover with an amp. So for an example, buying both a Kicker KX2 (03KX2), a monoblock amp for the sub, and a 4 channel amp for the four 6.5" speakers.

It's a extended cab truck with no in cabin trunk space and the speakers are 50/60w RMS, and I'm looking for a smallish sub in the 300w range, so I favor the PIONEER TSSWX2502.

**QUESTION: If I split the rear inputs with a cross over will it lower the impedance and burn up the head unit?**

Comment: Personally, I always run a separate amp. You're asking for a 5-channel amplifier. There are a lot of good ones, just find one in your price range. It's easy to get hung up on the brand and worry about the quality but in my experience as long as the install is good, the slap will be good enough for daily driving.

Comment: As you have this posted, it's actually *off-topic*. You are seeking purchase recommendations. If you would, figure out what *you think might work* and reword your question to ask if it will. We cannot make the decisions for you.

Comment: Maybe if the question was changed to pros/cons of 4+mono/5 channel amps

Comment: I suggest you remove 2nd and 3rd paragraphs to avoid subjectivity.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the details you have provided, your system is as follows:

- 4 Ohm coaxial speakers rated at 60w RMS (4)
- 4 Ohm subwoofer rated at approximately 400w RMS [SVC](http://knowledge.sonicelectronix.com/car-audio-and-video/car-subwoofers/what-are-the-differences-between-single-and-dual-voice-coil-subwoofers/) (1)

Your options include those you have mentioned which are common:

1. A single 5 channel amp
2. 4 channel amp + monoblock amp

Having a separate amp for the mids/highs and lows allows you to have more flexibility in your system for future upgrades. For example, if you wanted to get an additional subwoofer, having a 5 channel amp with a lot of power in a single channel (800w+ RMS) can be be rare and more expensive. A single 5 channel amp can be cleaner and easier to install.

This is basically what you need to look for in an amplifier if you go with either option:

- RMS Power @ 4 ohms 60 watts x 4 channels (Full range channels)
- RMS Power @ 4 ohms 400 watts x 1 channel (Subwoofer channel)

You'll want to **match or exceed** the RMS power of your speaker with your amp. The specs above are the bare minimum of what you should look for. [This](http://www.crutchfield.com/S-CYB9JOJJ30Z/learn/learningcenter/car/amplifiers/shopping_guide.html) article from Crutchfield can provide you with more information on what to look for in an amplifier. They also suggest that your amp power should be rated at 75% more than your speaker's RMS rating (although I have never heard this number until now, use your discretion).

Do you need a crossover?

The majority of coaxial speakers already contain crossover within them so an external one is not needed. Multi-channel amplifiers will usually have high-pass and low-pass filters built in which serve as a crossover. It all depends on what you want in your system and how much you're willing to spend. [Here](http://www.crutchfield.com/S-mDmQCcnzSo9/learn/learningcenter/car/crossovers_faq.html) is another article from Crutchfield with more information on crossovers.

If I split the rear inputs with a cross over will it lower the impedance and burn up the head unit?

With electronic crossovers (like the one you're leaning towards), the load of the speakers will be handled by the amp and the crossover will have no effect on impedance. With passive crossovers, you would probably want to ensure you are getting the impedance you require by testing with a multimeter if you are using something custom or not designed for your speakers. Passive crossovers usually are included with speakers that require them.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is probably one of the best ways to accomplish what you want done.  I am 99% positive there is no single component (for a vehicle) that does everything you want.

If you ask your question in a more general way and don't ask for recommendations, you'll get a lot better responses.